# Les « accointances » avec/entre des inanimés ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

> D'aucuns, chez les journalistes en cinéma, ont évoqué l'environnement
>   de Martin Scorsese. On pense par exemple à Taxi Driver, sorti en 1976.
>   Bien au fait de ces comparaisons, M. Ames estime qu'il y a davantage
>   d'accointances avec l'univers de The French Connection de William
>   Friedkin. ([La Presse](http://www.lapresse.ca/arts/livres/201804/20/01-5161870-jonathan-ames-joaquin-phoenix-est-comme-un-animal-sauvage.php))
>
> ---
>
> Première femme élue présidente en Corée du Sud, Mme Park a été
>   destituée et arrêtée en mars 2017 pour toute une série d'accusations
>   qui ont mis en lumière les accointances troubles entre le pouvoir
>   politique et les grands conglomérats familiaux. ([La Presse/AFP](http://www.lapresse.ca/international/asie-oceanie/201804/16/01-5161166-corruption-lex-presidente-sud-coreenne-park-renonce-a-faire-appel.php))

Dans le dictionnaire on trouve plusieurs exemples de l'*accointance* avec des [personnes](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/accointance).

---

- Qu'est-ce qu'*accointance* veut dire dans ces deux exemples et est-ce que c'est possible autant avec des personnes qu'avec des inanimés ?
- Est-ce que ce sont des emplois typiques de l'*accointance* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'après le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/accointance), la première définition d'accointance est :

> A. Relations familières ou d'intérêt.
>
> 1. [Avec des pers. considérées ou haut placées] :

Les accointances entre le pouvoir politique et les conglomérats familiaux font clairement partie de cette définition, il n'y a rien de figuré ici. Il s'agit de relations d'intérêt (où intérêt signifie « [Intérêt personnel, attachement égoïste à ce qui est avantageux pour soi sans égard pour autrui, en partic. dans le domaine pécuniaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/int%C3%A9r%C3%AAt) »), c.-à-d. que ce sont des relations où chacun a ses propres intérêts en vue. Le pouvoir politique se fait financer par les conglomérats, et ceux-ci en retirent de l'influence politique.

---

La deuxième définition d'accointance (toujours le TLFi) est :

> B. Commerce amoureux hors mariage, liaison entre deux personnes de sexe différent

Pour les deux univers littéraires, c'est bien sûr au sens figuré, deux univers littéraires ne peuvent pas avoir de liaison amoureuse au sens propre. Il faudra demander à l'auteur pour savoir exactement ce qu'il avait en tête, mais on peut imaginer par exemple que les deux univers se sont inspiré l'un avec l'autre, ou bien que les thèmes sont similaires, etc.